# Use multiple classes in other namespaces

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

If I have some php classes inside a namespace `com\test`

and want to import all of them into another php file how can do that?

```
use com\test\ClassA
use com\test\ClassB
...
```

`use com\test\*`  give me syntax error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
use com\test;

$a = new \test\ClassA;
$b = new \test\ClassB;
```

or

```
use com\test\ClassA as ClassA;
use com\test\ClassB as ClassB;

$a = new ClassA;
$b = new ClassB;
```

See the [PHP manual on Using namespaces: Aliasing/Importing](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

Comment: Very boring! Hope PHP developers will put that feature.

Comment: Agreed. I realize that it is to prevent naming collisions but honestly - .NET, Java, and others have been doing it for years. Is is it so hard to throw a fatal error instead of forcing us to have ugly syntax?

Comment: the first example would be referring to classes in the namespace `test` not `com\test`, you would have to remove the beginning "\" for it to be using the alias `test`

Comment: @lagbox is right, the beginning "\" for the alias new test\ClassA and test\ClassB will give Fatal error.

Answer (score 32):

> From PHP 7.0 onwards, classes, functions, and constants being imported from the same namespace can be grouped together in a single `use` statement.

Like this way:

```php
use com\test\{ClassA, ClassB};
    
$a = new ClassA;
$b = new ClassB;
```

Read more here: [PHP Manual for Aliasing/Importing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do such thing.

You can do:

```
 use com\test
```

and refer to your classes at later time as:

```
test\ClassA
test\ClassB
```